# I cant seem to update a table row in my database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to update a row in table by submitting a form. Although it works for my add button, I cant seem to update it using update(a tag).

NOTE: The edit button is in the last column in each row as well as the delete button.

I want to update it and this is how i tried. I already tried the isset, get and i still cant get it to work. I badly really need  help for this one.

```
<?php
include("update-form.php");          
$query = "SELECT tbl_members.MemberID, tbl_members.LastName, tbl_members.FirstName, tbl_members.Gender, tbl_plans.PlanName, tbl_membership.StartDate, tbl_membership.EndDate, tbl_members.JoinDate, tbl_members.Email, tbl_members.PhoneNumber 
            FROM tbl_members 
            JOIN tbl_membership ON tbl_members.MemberID = tbl_membership.MemberID 
            JOIN tbl_plans ON tbl_plans.PlanID = tbl_membership.PlanID;";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['MemberID']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['LastName']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['FirstName']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Gender']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['PlanName']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['StartDate']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['EndDate']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['JoinDate']."</td>";

    echo "<td class='crudButton'>"
    .

            "<a class='click open-updateModal' data-id='".$row['MemberID']."'> 
                <span class='material-icons-sharp'>
                edit
                </span>".                                       
            "</a>".

            "<a class='click open-deleteModal'>".
                "<span class='material-icons-sharp'>delete</span>".
            "</a>".

         "</td>";
         
    echo "</tr>";
}                                    
?>   


<?php 

    if(isset($_POST['update_submit'])){
        $id = isset($_GET['MemberID']);
        $fName = $_POST['firstname'];
        $lName = $_POST['lastname'];
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];
        $birthDate = $_POST['birthdate'];
        $address = $_POST['address'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        
        $edit_query = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE tbl_members SET FirstName='$fName', LastName='$lName', Gender ='$gender', DateOfBirth = '$birthDate', Address = '$address', PhoneNumber = '$phone' WHERE MemberID='$id';") or die("error occurred");

        if($edit_query){
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
        }
    }

    else{
    ?>    
        <dialog class="update-modal" id="modal">
        <div class="modal-form" method="dialog">
            <div class="head">
                <span class="material-icons-sharp">
                    edit
                </span>
                <h1> EDIT INFO </h1>
            </div>
                                    
            <form method="post">
                <div class="fillup-form">                               
                    <div class="block-1">
                        <label for="">First Name:</label><br>
                        <input type="text" name="firstname" value="" required><br><br>
                        <label for="">Last Name:</label><br>
                        <input type="text" name="lastname" value="" required><br><br>
                        <label for="">Date Of Birth:</label><br>
                        <input type="date" name="birthdate" value="" required><br><br>
                        <label for="">Gender:</label><br>
                        <input type="text" name="gender" value="" required><br><br>
                        <label for="">Address:</label><br>
                        <input type="text" name="address" value="" required><br><br>
                        <label for="">Phone Number:</label><br>
                        <input type="text" name="phone" value="" required><br><br>
                                
                    </div>

                </div>
                                                            
                <div class="buttons">
                    <button class="click close-updateModal">Cancel</button>
                    <button class="click submit-updateModal" name="update_submit">Submit</button>  
                </div>                                
            </form>

    </div>                                                  
</dialog>


<?php
    }
?>
//this javascript is included as well
//update dialog
const modal2 = document.querySelector('.update-modal');
const open_updateModals = document.querySelectorAll('.open-updateModal');
const close_updateModal = document.querySelector('.close-updateModal');

for (let open_updateModal of open_updateModals) {
    open_updateModal.addEventListener('click', () => {
        modal2.showModal();
    });
}

close_updateModal.addEventListener('click', () => {
    modal2.close();

})
```

Comment: "can't seem to" isn't an error message or useful problem statement. What specifically is going wrong, based on your testing so far? See also [ask]. Tell us about an error message, warning, unexpected output, unexpected path that the code takes, or whatever, based on your debugging efforts. Remember we can't run your code so it's not sufficient to simply dump the code on us with no meaningful explanation of what happens when you execute it. Thanks.

Comment: I can observe though that 1) `$_GET['MemberID']` won't exist during a POST request from your form, because the form's postback URL likely won't include that value on the query string of the URL it defaults to. What URL is it posting back to currently? If there's no `?MemberID=123` bit on that URL, then that's a big part of your problem. Try making an `action` for the form which includes that in the URL, or including MemberID as an `<input type="hidden"` in your form (and then accessing it via `$_POST` in the PHP.

Comment: And also 2) `isset()` returns either `true` or `false` (you can read this in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) already) so `$id = isset($_GET['MemberID']);` is never going to get you the $id (regardless of my first point) - it's not clear why you put `isset` there, in this context. Therefore I'd assume that your SQL query is either crashing, or at least failing to update any rows, due to the query not receiving a valid ID value. Does that match with your testing results? Or are there additional problems as well?

Comment: Thank you! I understand now but my main problem is how do i get the member id from the row of which edit button that i clicked to use it to update? Do i set the value of <input type="hidden" to value=$_GET['MeberID] like this?

Comment: Read my last comment again, I already told you two options

Comment: Thank you sir but can you be more specific to the solution? im sorry im really new to this. What's really going on here is when i clicked the edit button, a form inside a dialog(the dialog it self will popup) should popup as i add an evenlistener clicked to it to showModal. By that being said, i need to get the id in that row in which i clicked the edit button to use the id in the update query.

Comment: You already got the record ID in the `data-id` attribute of the link that you are clicking to trigger your modal, so - read it from there in your event handler code.

Comment: P.S. Not sure where you've been learning from, but this is totally the wrong way to build a SQL query using PHP when you're incorporating user input into it. 1) It's vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and 2) it can be crashed with simple syntax issues due to the input values  - e.g. anyone with a `'` in their name (such as `O'Reilly`)  would crash your query because SQL would think the `'` was terminating the input string after the `O`.

Comment: Instead you must use prepared statements and parameters to correctly build the query and insert the values safely. See [How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement), [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli for some excellent resources and simple examples of how to do this stuff properly. Even as a beginner on a practice project you should get into good habits.

Comment: Also please bring your SQL error handling into the 21st century. Add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before your `mysqli_connect()` (or `new mysqli()`) command, and this will ensure that errors with your SQL queries are reported correctly to PHP automatically. That way you don't need to clutter your script with repetitive code to keep checking errors after every mysqli command. And you should never be echoing error data deliberately - it can easily reveal sensitive info to attackers by accident. In a live environment you should always log all PHP errors to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues:

1. `$_GET['MemberID']` won't exist during a POST request from your form, because the form's postback URL likely won't include that value on the query string of the URL it defaults to. If there's no `?MemberID=123` bit on that URL after you submit the form, then that's a big part of your problem
2. `isset()` returns either `true` or `false` (as per the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)) so `$id = isset($_GET['MemberID']);` is never going to get you the $id (regardless of my first point) - it's not clear why you put `isset()` there, in this context.
3. You need to pass the member ID into the form at the time an "edit" button is clicked. The ID is currently stored in the `data-id` attribute of the Edit button, so you can use JavaScript to retrieve it and put it into a hidden field in your form.

Add a field into your form like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="memberID" id="editMemberID" value="">
```

and then amend your JavaScript like this:

```
  open_updateModal.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var id = this.dataset.id;
    document.querySelector("#editMemberID").value = id;
    modal2.showModal();
  });
```

That way, when the form is submitted you can write

```
if(isset($_POST['update_submit'])){
    $id = $_POST['MemberID'];
```

to get the ID.

---

Lastly please note my comments on the thread above regarding the problems with the way you're building your SQL query and handling errors from it. You seem to have been following a very outdated and poor-quality tutorial in that respect.

Comment: Thank you very much sir this is big help for me for the school project we are doing. Also will be looking to that preventing sql injection thing too. Very much appreciated :))